# Reverse proxy with URL rewrite issues for check_mk and nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, check-mk

I'm trying to run check_mk in docker behind a proxy, but I'm having problems with not being able to set the check_mk base_url.

So check_mk is running on http://somehost:6000/sitename/check_mk/ and I need to access it from https://example.com/prefix/check_mk/

I have the following nginx setup:

```
location /prefix/check_mk/ {
    proxy_pass http://somehost:6000;
    rewrite ^/prefix/check_mk/(.*) /sitename/check_mk/$1 break;
}
```

I also have the following proxy config

proxy_http_version 1.1;

```
             # add server_port if we are not running on a standard port or a iptables nat to a standard port
             proxy_set_header Host              $host;
             proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip         $remote_addr;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
             proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
```

I can access check_mk for the first time at https://example.com/prefix/check_mk/index.py

However, all links in the returned page are invalid because they're not aware of the proxy. So they're things like https://example.com/checkmksitename/check_mk/dashboard.py instead of https://example.com/prefix/dashboard.py

How do I get something like this working behind a proxy when it doesn't support a base URL to build its links off ?

Answer (score 1):

This is like WAY too late, but I stumbled upon this and ended up figuring it out. This has to be in your location block:

```
proxy_pass_header Authorization;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_request_buffering off;
client_max_body_size 0;
proxy_read_timeout  36000s;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
proxy_hide_header x-frame-options;
```

It may be a little more than needed, but it's what worked for me. Best of luck!